# Error when applying snmp.set --v3targets on vcenter 6.7U1

Tags: vmware-vcenter, snmpv3

I have vcenter appliance 6.7U1 and I have successfully tested my SNMPv3 configuration on vcenter with paessler snmp tester, but the last step was to add a trap target.

I am facing a strange issue with this command trying to assign a target for SNMPv3 as follows:

```
snmp.set --v3targets=192.168.1.1@161/snmpuser/priv/trap

Error in method: The SNMP v3 target format is invalid. The format to use is: ip-or-hostname[@port]/remote-user/security-level trap|inform[,...]. (code com.vmware.applmgmt.err_snmp_badv3_target)
```

I need help because I can't figure what the correct format is anymore on vcenter.

Edit, I should mentione that snmpuser contains special characters.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears if snmpuser contains special characters! It is possible to create such users on ESXi servers, and on vcenter appliance, but you can't use this user in the v3targets as it can't be parsed correctly and snmp service will no longer work, this is not mentioned in the documentation. You have to dig deeper to find out what the real error is, as I modified /etc/vmware/snmp.xml manually, I discovered I am no longer able to start/stop snmp service on vcenter appliance, pitty.. It took me like 20 hours to figure out what the issue was because I was relying on the fact that it worked for ESXi...